# Expose class to global, typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

SomeClass.ts:

```
  export class SomeClass{
      constructor(){} 

    }
```

index.html:

```
<script src="SomeClass.js"></<script> // compiled to es5
<script>
  var someClass = new SomeClass(); //SomeClass is not defined
</script>
```

I'm running es5 so I cant do any import stuff.

In normal javascript you can do:

```
(function(global){
    function SomeClass() {

    }
    global.IfcModel = IfcModel;
})(window);
```

**How do I expose a class in typescript on the window?**

The transpiled js file:

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var SomeClass = /** @class */ (function () {
        function SomeClass() {
        }
        return SomeClass;
    }());
    exports.SomeClass = SomeClass;
});
```

Comment: ES5 does not support classes or TypeScript either. You have to compile your TypeScript code to ES5 and bundle it into a module (e.g. using webpack) to use it in a normal `script` tag.

Comment: I have ES5 as target on ts.

Comment: What does your transpiled JS look like?

Comment: @MikeChamberlain. I've updated the question with the transpiled output.

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of "half" using modules. To do this, either don't use modules (remove the `export`), or use them consistently (e.g., make your second script a module that imports the class). Right now it's like half a handshake...

If you're publishing your library as TypeScript, note that TypeScript handles modules (v1.8 and above), so using modules doesn't force your users to use Webpack or similar; [more in this blog post](https://medium.com/@vivainio/with-latest-typescript-you-may-not-need-webpack-417d2ef0e773).

If you want them to be able to use it without using modules, don't use modules in the lib.

Comment: The window object get wrapped inside the class instead of outside when the file is transpiled. ...} window.SomeClass = SoomeClass });

Comment: If I put a console.log above it, it does not fire.

Comment: @Per: Ah, yeah, I guess nothing's requiring it, so the callback never runs. Hence the "instead" bit. :-) (Which is now the entire answer.)

Comment: The module system is transpiled to es5 code with typescript. But I need to reach it from my window object so I can use it in my es5-app.

Comment: @Per: As I said above: Either don't use the module system, or use it in both places. Don't *half* use it.

Comment: I want to half use it. I'm building a parser with typescript which uses the module system but is transpiled to es5. I want this to be usable from an es5 app. Just like jquery or any other library. Henche, I need to expose it to the window object.

Comment: @Per: You're confusing "in ES5" to "without modules." As I said in the original answer (but oddly removed when editing), use Webpack or similar (if TypeScript doesn't handle it itself) so you're using modules in **both places** (in the resulting ES5 output).

Comment: In that case I need to require users of my library to use webpack or similar. I don't want that.

Comment: @Per: You're *already* requiring them to use modules, by using modules. If you don't want to require that, don't use modules.

Comment: Hm. I thought typescript took care of the es5 transpiling.

Comment: @Per: It does. Again: ES5 != not using modules. I've just updated the answer, btw; TypeScript v1.8 and above handle modules directly, no need for Webpack or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
(window as any).yourInstanceName = new SomeClass();
```